# Convert HTML to PDF in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

1. I'm trying to generate a `PDF` out of my `HTML` page. This works fine if the data is bind to `td` directly from `ts`. If I try to bind the value to `input`, it doesn't read that. Below is the working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html-to-pdf-m-gau5nv) for the same.
2. If I try to generate PDF to my complete page the structure changes. It works perfect only for table. I'm using `jsPDF` for all the above. Is there any way so that I can print my complete page and generate a data URI?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**html**

```
<td id="myTd"><input [(ngModel)]="userName" type="text" 
[value]="userName"></td>
```

**ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular Html To Pdf ';
  userName: string;

  @ViewChild('pdfTable', {static: false}) pdfTable: ElementRef;


  public downloadAsPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    var x = document.getElementById("myTd");
    x.innerHTML = this.userName;

    const specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    const pdfTable = this.pdfTable.nativeElement;

    doc.fromHTML(pdfTable.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      width: 190,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });

   console.log(doc.output('dataurl'));
   console.log(this.userName);


  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html-to-pdf-m-oeji6j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It doesn't work this way. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html-to-pdf-m-fzz284

Comment: @Sai Manoj you need to add userName instead name in html input.Look answer

Comment: <td id="myTd"><input [(ngModel)]="userName" type="text" 
[value]="userName"></td>

Comment: That's not the case. I need to patch the value by default

Comment: Ya I know.But need to bind same name to ngModel

Comment: userName: string;

  @ViewChild('pdfTable', {static: false}) pdfTable: ElementRef;

Comment: I used userName name for that and it bind using     var x = document.getElementById("myTd");
    x.innerHTML = this.userName; to table

Comment: Got It, But if my page has lots of data to bind, I need to use n number of `ngModel`. Looking for a better approach. And don't the reason why it behaves strange for input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219165/discussion-between-janitha-rasanga-and-sai-manoj).